# Where can I get the source of Google Calendar with Lollipop?

Tags: android, calendar

I found a source that is https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git.
But It does not look like not the new App [on the play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar&hl=en).

Where is the correct source?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can. Google Calendar is not Android Calendar. Your link is stock Android calendar. Google Calendar is not open-source.